# pdfkit.from_string does not work in cloud run service

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, pdfkit

I have this flask endpoint which I already test locally and it works fine, it returns me a PDF, but when I deploy it to cloud run in GCP and I try to request that I get "Service unavailable" status 503, here is my code:

```
@app.route('/generate_pdf', methods=['POST'])
def generate_pdf():
    # Create the index page with pdfkit
    path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    html_file_path = "cover.html"
    if not os.path.exists(html_file_path):
        return "cover.html file not found.", 404
    
    with open(html_file_path, 'r') as file:
        index_page_html = file.read()
        # Replace placeholders in the HTML
    index_page_html = index_page_html.replace("{CUSTOMER_NAME}", "ARCA")
    index_page_html = index_page_html.replace("{PERIOD}", "2023-05")
    index_page_html = index_page_html.replace(
        "logo_customer.png", "logo_telmex.png")
    index_page_html = index_page_html.replace("fonts/",  path + "/fonts/")
    index_page_html = index_page_html.replace("images/", path + "/images/")

    options = {
        "enable-local-file-access": "",
        "page-height": 160,
        "page-width": 208,
    }
    index_pdf = "index.pdf"

    # Generate the PDF using pdfkit and save it to the temporary file
    pdfkit.from_string(index_page_html, index_pdf ,options=options)

    print(index_pdf)
    # Return the temporary file as a downloadable attachment
    return send_file(index_pdf, as_attachment=True)
```

I tried to change the directory to /tmp and I tried to use /app but both of them are not working, by the way this is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.11-slim

# Install wkhtmltopdf dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    libxrender1 \
    libxext6 \
    libfontconfig1 \
    libjpeg-dev \
    libpng-dev \
    libtiff-dev \
    libwebp-dev \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install wkhtmltopdf
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    ca-certificates \
    fontconfig \
    libssl-dev \
    libxrender1 \
    libxext6 \
    libpng-dev \
    wkhtmltopdf \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /app

# Copy requirements file
COPY requirements.txt .

# Install requirements
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

# Copy application files
COPY . .

# Set environment variables
ENV FLASK_APP=app.py
ENV FLASK_DEBUG=true

# Expose port 
EXPOSE $PORT

# Start the application using WSGI
CMD exec gunicorn --bind :$PORT wsgi:app --workers 2 --timeout 60
```